# disjoint union in Kotlin to get access in Java

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm working in a mixed Java - Kotlin project. There's a class Either:
https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture-Kotlin/blob/master/app/src/main/kotlin/com/fernandocejas/sample/core/functional/Either.kt

In one of the Java classes I'm getting an instance of Either as a parameter in such a way:

```
    AuthenticateUseCase.Params params = new AuthenticateUseCase.Params(username, password);
    authenticateUseCase.invoke(params, new Function1<Either<? extends Failure, ? extends TokenInfo>, Unit>() {
        @Override public Unit invoke(
            Either<? extends Failure, ? extends TokenInfo> either) {
                // TODO here goes some code
        }
    });
```

My question is how in the //TODO marked place get in Java the TokenInfo instance and call methods on it (assuming that it's a TokenInfo object (and not Failure) that is embedded in Either parameter).

thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you tried using code completion in your IDE?

Comment: yes but out of methods that I get none makes sense to me, it proposes me: isRight()  right(R b) . isLeft() and left(L a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I... really wouldn't use this class for anything. It may just be for a specific purpose (given `sample` in package name). But `either` really needs a type parameter and `left` and `right` methods don't make sense.

If you somehow have no choice, you should be able to call `either` like this:

```
@Override public Unit invoke(
    Either<? extends Failure, ? extends TokenInfo> either) {
        either.either(f -> ..., tokenInfo -> ...);
        return Unit.INSTANCE;
}
```

where `f -> ...` and `tokenInfo -> ...` are the Java lambdas taking `Failure` and `TokenInfo` respectively.